# SQL: Сортировать по релевантности.

Tags: search, like, mysql

Приветствую.

Есть запрос

```
select * from `article` where `content` rlike ?
```

где `?` может быть словом либо словами, разделенными `|`.

Можно ли сортировать по совпадениям? То есть наиболее подходящие должны вывестись выше тех, которые совпадают меньше.

К примеру, я ввел в строку `привет|дела|как|мир`.

Есть запись, которая содержит `мир как дела`, и запись `как дела`. В данном случае первым должно выходить `мир как дела`, так как совпадений со строкой больше.

Если это самокат, то поясните, как можно реализовать поиск по статьям, более подходящим способом.

Благодарю за внимание.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй MATCH AGAINST http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Fulltext_Search.html

Comment: Индекса у таблиц нету.

Answer (score 0):

Сделал пока что так, так как других идей нету.

```
    SELECT * FROM shorts
    WHERE content LIKE :str
    ORDER BY CASE
    WHEN content LIKE :one THEN 0
    WHEN content LIKE :two THEN 1
    WHEN content LIKE :three THEN 2
    WHEN content LIKE :four THEN 3
    ELSE 4
    END
```